# How does this point2LineDist() method works?

Tags: 2d, mathematics, javascript, trigonometry

I was browsing Wolf3D JS port and bump into [that method](https://github.com/id-Software/wolf3d-browser/blob/master/js/math.js#L243) :

```
/**
 * @description calculates distance between a point (x, y) and a line.
 * @memberOf Wolf.Math
 * @param {number} x X coord of point
 * @param {number} y Y coord of point
 * @param {number} a Line angle in degrees
 * @returns {number} Distance
 */
function point2LineDist(x, y, a) {
    return Math.abs( (x * SinTable[a] - y * CosTable[a]) >> 0);
}
```

I think I understand what it does. It gives shortest distance (green on picture) between a line (from angle) and a (x, y) point.

[image]

What is not clear to me is how it works.
I know a little bit of trigonometry, but I am not able to figure out which trigonometry identity or formula it use. The binary shift is (I think) a quick way to convert a float to an int.

Comment: There's a chance sinTable is just a sin() without using the Math.sin() function, same with cosZable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The direction vector of the red line is `(CosTable[a], SinTable[a])`. It is a unit vector.

Now consider the green line on your drawing. The vector along this line pointing towards `(x, y)` is orthogonal to the direction vector, and its value is `(SinTable[a], -CosTable[a])`. It is a unit vector, too.

From there, the distance between point `(x, y)` and the red line, which is the length of the green line, is the dot product between vector `(x, y)` and the orthogonal vector. This is where the formula comes from. The `abs()` call is here because one must account for direction vectors pointing in the other direction.

Comment: Yes you are right, its a simple dot product. It should have popped to my mind.